# String changes its value causing a java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

I am loading a document from a file, this file (which is in a URL) for some reason changes its name causing the java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Although I use a user input I have tried putting the name of the file directly, but it shows the same error.

```
File input = new File("/example/");
```

I expect the file name to be `/example/`, but the debugging shows it to be `\example`

Comment: Would it be fair to say the only code relevant to your question is `File input = new File("/"+ userPage +"/");`?

Comment: *I expect the file name to be /example/, but the output is \example* You are running on Windows, the path separator on that platform is ``\``; using `File` you are going to get a local path (which is going to use the path separator). Instead, pass the `String` without building a `File`. `/example/` is not a URL. `new URL("file:///example")` would be a URL. It isn't clear what you're trying to do here beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously running your code in a Windows OS, which uses `'\'` as its file path separator character.

`File` automatically converts file separators (`'/'` and `'\'`), no matter what is specified in the String path, to the local file system's separator, thereby using the normalized *local* form, which is what you are seeing.

Your path is a *absolute* path, so the `example` file should be in the root directory. If you are expecting the file to be relative to where you are running your app from, remove the leading `/` to make it a *relative* path.